# Tomcat App Reverse Proxy with Apache http server

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy

i have two app in tomcat which is running in

1. http://192.168.0.101:8080/app1/
2. http://192.168.0.102:8080/app2/

I have apache http server running on another system http://192.168.0.100/

Let, i have a public ip connected to 192.168.0.100 server.
I want to configure two domain of mine pointed towards http server.

- Domain 1: one.app.com
- Domain 2: two.app.com

How i can i use apache http server as a revrse proxy of tomcat app ?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName one.app.com
<Location / >
    ProxyPass http://192.168.0.101:8080/app1/
    SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Above config just redirect me to http://192.168.0.101:8080/app1/ :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName one.app.com
    SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

    ProxyPass /app1 http://192.168.0.101:8080/app1/
    ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://192.168.0.101:8080/app1/

    ProxyPass /app2 http://192.168.0.102:8080/app2/
    ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://192.168.0.102:8080/app2/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Got it. But my app has static contents mapped as /app1/css/style.css which is trying to get as : http://one.app.com/app1/css/style.css and thus no css. :(

Comment: are you using full path names in your html/javascript file ? if so - its a good practice to change to relative paths

Comment: Don't put /app1/ in your HREF.  Just use "css/style.css"